# Установить psql на Debian

Tags: postgresql, psql

Как установить только psql, для управления базой?

База стоит на другой машине.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ apt search postgresql-client
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
postgresql-client/xenial-pgdg 9.6+182.pgdg16.04+1 all
  front-end programs for PostgreSQL (supported version)

postgresql-client-9.1/xenial-pgdg 9.1.24-1.pgdg16.04+1 amd64
  front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.1

postgresql-client-9.2/xenial-pgdg 9.2.21-1.pgdg16.04+1 amd64
  front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.2

postgresql-client-9.3/xenial-pgdg 9.3.17-1.pgdg16.04+1 amd64
  front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.3

postgresql-client-9.4/xenial-pgdg 9.4.12-1.pgdg16.04+1 amd64
  front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.4

postgresql-client-9.5/xenial-pgdg 9.5.7-1.pgdg16.04+1 amd64
  front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.5

postgresql-client-9.6/xenial-pgdg,now 9.6.3-1.pgdg16.04+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.6

postgresql-client-common/xenial-pgdg,now 182.pgdg16.04+1 all [installed,automatic]
  manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
```

Comment: а потом apt install postgresql-client-9.6./jessie-backports 9.6.2-1~bpo8+1 amd64 ?

Comment: думаю, просто `apt install postgresql-client-9.6`